# Acessing Javascript function through applet

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to pass to a javascript function some values from my Java Applet

```
JSObject.getWindow(ui).eval("foo(123)");
```

`ui`: My FormMain.

What happens that the my javascript function called "foo", don't run ? My "foo" functions has just an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your function placed? Maybe it belongs to another execution context. When you call 'eval', it is executed in the global context. So, please provide the exact place where your javascript function is.

Comment: my javascrip function are in the same .aspx page that are my applet tag.

Comment: Can you please provide the link to your page? if you have it online, to be able to debug it. I assume it's the issue with execution context. There is also the possibility that javascript is not loaded yet when you are calling this function from java.